# xml to json using scala?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to convert XML to JSON using Scala,then save to Elasticsearch.
I am getting the index in Elasticsearch "xmltojson", but the index is empty, please help me to solve this problem.

here is the code :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.json4s.Xml.toJson
import scala.xml.XML
import org.apache.spark._
import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._

object XmlToJson {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("XmlToJson").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc= new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    val df = sqlContext.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .option("rowTag", "book")
      .load("/home/aymenstien/Bureau/aymen/jsonfiles/VOICE CDR.xml")

    val tojson = df.toJSON
    tojson.saveToEs("xmltojson/people")
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your xml?

Comment: Is the conversion successful and what ES client are you using?